# Copy-paste is not working in Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android-studio

I am facing a weird issue with Mac version of Android Studio (i.e., I am not able to copy (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) any text). I have no idea why it is behaving strange like this. My question may be silly, but I have been facing this issue since I started working from **Windows** to **Mac**. Any solutions and alternatives would be much helpful for me. I am completely stuck with this issue for the past two days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several reasons why you could be experiencing this

- You are using [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) and Android studio doesn't like it
- Your keybinding is messed up.

To solve keybinding issue press **File -> Settings** and check what the keybindings are, you have maybe changed it or imported settings from somebody else. See the image as a reference.

**Note: the filter of copy, you need to do this for paste too.**

[image]

To fix the issue with ClipMenu.

- Right click on "Application/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app"
- choose "Show Package Contents"
- edit `bin/idea.properties`
- add this property `ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True`
- restart IntelliJ IDEA.

There is a [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114252) issue with further information

Comment: The options showing cmnd+c. But i couldn't perform copy action

Comment: @Chandru what about paste? Does copy-paste work outside Android studio?

Comment: copy and paste works outside android studio. I am facing this issue only inside the android studio editor

Answer (score 3):

> this worked for me
>
> go to file menu and click on invalidate Caches/Restart ,after this confirm the dialog open .

Answer (score 2):

Go to File-> Setting->Editor(Under IDE Settings)->Change value of maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard to 1(Under Limits section)

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue due to [PopClip](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/popclip/id445189367) I have to disable it to get the keyboard shortcuts working.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your keymaps aren't messed up. Go to Android Studio > Preferences > Keymap > Main Menu > Edit. If copy and paste are set correctly there, then it must be something else in your system that's stopping it

Comment: keymaps are displaying correct. I guess problem should be as like what you said. But i couldn't trigger it out :-(

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug with my ClipMenu (on Mac) while set `useNativeClipboard=true`.

I solved the problem by using ClipMenu to paste file into Android Studio (show menu of ClipMenu, then select item)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `Ctrl c` is occupied by other programs(my case is "Oulu Dictionary" program).

Try to check if other programs have global shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0):

disable the plugin Ideavm if installed under settings>plugins>installed.