# Android Studio copy and paste issue when cloning repository from git

Tags: android, copy, repository, paste

This may be a simple question to answer, but i really cannot find anywhere to fix this issue. If anyone knows why this is happening, please let me know because this is so annoying.

OS that I am using      : MacOS Sierra

Android Studio Version  : 2.2.3

**There are TWO issues that I am having in Android Studio**

**Issue #1.** **Copy and paste does not work in the edittext box where to put git repository url.**

To be more specific, File --> New --> Project from Version Control --> Git --> I see pop-up window like below attached image where I put git repository url to clone some project.

[image: Issue #1]

**COPY any url from github and PASTE into the git repository URL is not working!**

Just in case someone may misguide me to fix the keybindings [like this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355151/copy-paste-is-not-working-in-android-studio-on-mac), I already tried and it is not the issue i am having with.

**Issue #2.** **This issue is similar to Issue #1. File --> New --> Project from Version Control --> Github will get result like the image below.**

[image: Issue #2]

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: I guess you need to give a new directory name for the first query. Please provide a GitHub link which has this issues.

Comment: rename GitTest directory..something else

Comment: @Sp4Rx the git repository url (http://github.com/mygithubid/GitTest.git) is there when I click File->New->Project from Version Conrol -> Git. Is that a normal behavior?

Comment: To add, copy some url and PASTE is not working. I have to manually type the url that I want to clone. Any idea?

Comment: I understand your problem. It has been there for a long time. I guess in some old version it worked well. Did you find a solution? Is it fixed in newer versions?

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur Right, I spent so long trying to figure out what the problem was, but i could not solve it. I tried upgrading to newer versions, too. It also didn't work. Instead, I completely removed Android Studio from my Mac OS X [How to Completely Removed Android Studio From Mac OS X](https://gist.github.com/tahmidsadik112/f08356d14a85d898299a) and downloaded it again and it works!

Comment: Hey @JayB Kim, found any solution? I have same issue in Window.

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya What I did was to completely remove the Android Studio and reinstalled it. It worked fine now! Since you are using Window,
 [you can try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10).

Comment: @JayB Kim Thanks! a lot, let me try

Comment: You can check this box and try it. Someone has solved it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6nz3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Issue1# Different repositories cannot be stored in same folders.
Issue2# Just login first when prompted then you can clone github repositories.

Refer: http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html

[Import Android Studio project from git into Android Studio (Gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127943/import-android-studio-project-from-git-into-android-studio-gradle)

http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/

https://medium.com/@akbarsha03/version-control-system-using-git-on-android-studio-a632eb00bea9

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have no luck solving my issues after looking at those links. Issue #1 is not about the existing repository. That git url is just there when I click "Git" tab. The issue is about PASTING URL is not working. For example, I have a github project that I want to clone in Android Studio, so I copy that url and try to PASTE that url. But pasting is not working. I have to manually type the url that I want to clone.