# Copy&Cut&Paste/Autocomplete doesn't work as expected in Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

Just started to learn Android development, following Udacity exercise *Exercise: Toying with FavoriteToys*. I noticed that `cmd + c`, `cmd + x` doesn't work as expected.(please note it does work in all other apps) 
Please look at the following image:
[image]

1. I can cp&ps the comments as expected (i.e line 43 can be copied)
2. I can't copy the *code* (for instance if I try to copy all line 28 it won't copy it, instead it will use the old clipboard i.e will take the comment on line 43 that I just copied)
3. I can copy only several characters (for instance if I copy few characters from the end of line 31 it will work)
4. I can copy the whole line 29 (that's the only one line of code that I CAN copy)

What did I try:

- Restart IDE
- Restart Mac
- Reset Cache/ Rebuild and all other woodo stuff
- Edited `idea.properties` with `ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True`
- My Key mapper looks fine, attaching img (as far as I can see)
- Reinstalling Android Studio (3.5)
- I don't have ClipMenu

Key Mapper:
[image: Key Mapper]

Possible Duplicate:
[Copy-paste is not working in Android Studio on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355151/copy-paste-is-not-working-in-android-studio-on-mac/30355339)

Will really appreciate any help, Thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that some other features didn't work as well, like highlighting and autocomplete in `.java`  classes. (it did work in the `.xml`)
I uninstalled *Android Studio 3.5*  [Uninstall](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)
Install the new version 3.5.1 [Android Studio Installation](https://developer.android.com/studio)

Really curious if other people had these issues if so, it just UNBELIEVABLE that such a release was made public.

(btw, upgrade to a higher version from Android Studio wasn't possible due to 
 *some conflicts were found in the installation area android studio*  error)